# How to convert jpg files into png files with linux command? + Difficulty = Subfolders

Tags: linux, png, directory, jpeg, mogrify

I want to convert several jpg files into png files. As far as I know, one can use this command

```
mogrify -format png *.*
```

I have one problem, I have a lot of subfolders. Let's say **a** is my main folder and **b,c** and **d** are subfolders. The images are in the subfolders.

How can I convert all images without having to open every folder manually?

-> I would like to write a command that works, when I am in folder **a**, but works for all files in the subfolders.

Comment: `sudo apt install imagemagick` for anyone curious

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Assuming you're in **folder a** the following might work for you

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec mogrify -format png {} \;
```

You can use the find command to get all the jpg files in all the subfolders and pass your command as an argument to find